# Processing items within a powershell array - multiple items

Tags: powershell

I have been reading about arrays in powershell and hash tables, I know the basic workings of an array and how to use foreach loop to get items within the array, my challange here is slightly different. I would like to pay what I call a multi dimension array to a script, and process the items contained within the array.

**What is my setup.**

```
 $x = (1,"Server1",3,1),(4,"Server2",6,2),(3,"Server3",4,3)
 $k = 'serverid','servername','locationid','appid'    # key names correspond to data positions in each array in $x
 $h = @{}
      
      
 For($i=0;$i -lt $x[0].length; $i++){
     $x |
         ForEach-Object{
             [array]$h.($k[$i]) += [string]$_[$i]
         }
               
               
 }
```

**What am i trying to achieve ?**

I am trying to achieve the structure of a database table within powershell. So literally treating each array item as a row.

So for example

(1,"Server1",3,1),(4,"Server2",6,2),(3,"Server3",4,3)

could be thought of as a table like below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8WVN.png)

I then want to loop for each item in the array to get the values, similar to the below example

```
[0].serverid = 1, [0].servername = server1, [0].locationid = 3, [0].applicationID = 1

[1].serverid = 4, [1].servername = server2, [1].locationid = 6, [1].applicationID = 2
```

**what have I done ?**

```
$x = (1,"Server1",3,1),(4,"Server2",6,2),(3,"Server3",4,3)
 $k = 'serverid','servername','locationid','appid'    # key names correspond to data positions in each array in $x
 $h = @{}


 For($i=0;$i -lt $x[0].length; $i++){
     $x |
         ForEach-Object{
             [array]$h.($k[$i]) += [string]$_[$i]
         }


 } 

$x


for ($i = 0; $i -lt $x.Count; $i++)
{
    $myserverid = $x[$i][0]
    $myservername = $x[$i][1]
    $mylocationid = $x[$i][2]
    $myappid = $x[$i][3]

    write-host $myserverid
}
```

**The Issues**

If I set the following    $x = (1,"Server1",3,1), then the loop is somewhat incorrect which is why I think the approach is wrong (more than one item works i.e   $x = (1,"Server1",3,1),(4,"Server2",6,2),(3,"Server3",4,3)). The loop only works if you have more than one item within the array, hence why I want to re-examine the way the loop works.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks for the answer below, when testing I noticed an issue with using the unary operator by adding a "," this works when used inside a variable, but doesn't work when passed to a file like the example. Create a file called test.ps1 
`param ([array[]]$servers)
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $servers.Count; $i++)
{
    $myserverid = $servers[$i][0]
    $myservername = $servers[$i][1]
    $mylocationid = $servers[$i][2]
    $myappid = $servers[$i][3]
    write-host " $myserverid  and $myservername and $mylocationid and $myappid"
}
` .\tester.ps1  -servers ,(1,'Server1',3,1)` fails

Comment: To pass a nested array as an _argument_, you must wrap it in `(...)` as a whole: `.\tester.ps1 -servers (,(1,'Server1',3,1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your approach relies on a *nested* (jagged) array**: That is, you have an array of subarrays, each of which represents the tuple of values you want to assign to properties.

**If there's only *one* subarray, you must create the nested array *explicitly*, using the unary form of `,`** the [array constructor operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-):

```
# Construct a 1-element array that contains the 4-element subarray.
$x = , (1,"Server1",3,1)
```

With *two or more*, subarrays, you *implicitly* get a nested array:

```
# Construct a 3-element array, each element of which contains a 4-element subarray.
$x = (1,"Server1",3,1), (4,"Server2",6,2), (3,"Server3",4,3)
```

---

Note that in PSv5+ you could use a custom class to solve your problem:

```
class Custom {
  [int] $serverid; [string] $servername;[int] $locationid; [int] $appid
  Custom($propValueArray) {
    $this.serverid = $propValueArray[0]; $this.servername = $propValueArray[1]; $this.locationid = $propValueArray[2]; $this.appid = $propValueArray[3]
  }
}

# Use an array cast to construct [Custom] instances.
# Note the need for (...) around the array, because casts have high
# precedence in PowerShell.
[Custom[]] ((1,"Server1",3,1), (4,"Server2",6,2), (3,"Server3",4,3))
```

This would allow for processing such as:

```
# Construct all objects
$objects = [Custom[]] ((1,"Server1",3,1), (4,"Server2",6,2), (3,"Server3",4,3))

# Process each object.
foreach ($object in $objects) {
   ($myserverid = $object.serverid) # assign a property to a var; `()` also outputs
   # ...
}
```